# Getting "\" sign inside HTML script in joomla

Tags: php, html, joomla, joomla-module

For a few months now I've been working on a Joomla-site and everything was OK till today.

Today I started working on one module that I finished yesterday, but I got something strange.

First, when I logged in today, this is what was waiting for me:

[image]

As I starting working, I saw that this error doesn't affect my work. But after a while, I saw something strange:
Everytime I was saving, entering or exiting the module I was editing, inside my HTML script i got this character: `\`.

[[image]]

This never happened before, and I've made/edited several Joomla templates, I have some knowledge in PHP, HTML and CSS, but never got this kind of error/stuff.

Is it possible that this happened because of the error I got when I logged into my admin panel (Error: Your host needs to disable magic_quotes_gpc to run this version of Joomla!) and should I wait for my host to resolve this or is it possible that something else happened, maybe something I did and didn't notice?

Comment: magic quotes automatically runs addslashes to all data sent over get post and cookie. So yes, those slashes are added by the error you saw. The only fix is for them to turn it off. You can try to turn it off yourself as some hosts do allow for custom php.ini or .htaccess to override some stuff. This would depend on your host though. I would suggest finding a new host or hosting yourself, unless you like someone being able to make changes to your server.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for your quick answer. I'll wait for host response, I send them e-mail. I really need answer from some expert to know where error is. Now, after knowing where to start and what is it, I know how to fix it. Thanks from the bottom of my hart!

Comment: I would suggest trying to open a support ticket and mark it as priority if possible. Or calling and raising hell as this type of change will break most sites that aren't expecting it. Be proactive in getting it fixed, don't just wait for them.

Comment: Also, upgrade your version of PHP (or find a host that will). Magic Quotes were removed in PHP 5.4 so this could not happen. So you're using 5.3 or less, and you should ideally be using something newer than that. Even PHP 5.5 is "end of life" now.

Comment: They are not added by the error, the error is showing because they are being added because magic quotes is on. The error is just telling you how to fix the problem.

Comment: Found solution. Need to insert new php.ini file and edit .htacess file, done that and error is gone, also slashes are gone, too.

Thank you all for help ;)